# Change port for TeamCity web server

Tags: configuration, continuous-integration, teamcity, port

I installed TeamCity and got it working against my project. However, I have since realized that I don't want it the administration page to be configured on port 80. I'm going to have other websites on that server that I want on the default port. How do I change the configured port?

I wandered around the configurations a bit and looked through the administration settings but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

> The port number can be edited in the `<TeamCity home>/conf/server.xml` file, line `<Connector port="8111" protocol="HTTP/1.1"`.

from [Installing and Configuring the TeamCity server](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Installation+Quick+Start)

Comment: @jkohlhepp as simple as googling for "teamcity port" and picking the first result ;)

Comment: hmmm i did try a couple different google searches but apparently not that one

Comment: Look at answer @dthrasher! Without changing buildAgent.properties it does not work properly.

Answer (score 59):

To add to the answer provided by @sfussenegger you will also need to make sure that your build agents can still connect to the TeamCity server instance on the new port, or else your builds won't run.

To do this, you'll need to change the build agent configuration files to reflect the new `serverUrl` value. You can find this setting in the `C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties` file.