# TeamCity services are running but I can't access the web interface. Any ideas for troubleshooting?

Tags: teamcity

I have TeamCity installed on a Windows Server 2012 machine. I installed teamCity default installation as service. 
Later I added the Application Role and Web Server Role features to the Windows Server.
Now I can't access TeamCity's web interface (I got 404 error) although the TeamCity Server service is running, and the agents' service are running too.
Any ideas/directions on troubleshooting this ?

Comment: Do you need to change Team City's port as IIS is using the default one (port 80)? See this answer for how to do it without the web interface: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2387411/78496

Comment: In my case, the requirements was to keep TeamCity running on port 80 because there are other systems that depend on that. After a few hours of digging,  I found that you need to disable some stuff that could be hijacking port 80: [ IIS / SQL Server Reporting Services (ReportServer) / Web Deployment Agent Service (MsDepSvc) / BranchCache (PeerDistSvc) / Sync Share Service (SyncShareSvc) / World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) /  Internet Information Server (WAS, IISADMIN) ]

Comment: There is the related [Troubleshooting section](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server#InstallingandConfiguringtheTeamCityServer-TroubleshootingTeamCityInstallation) in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credit to [Ebeid Soliman El Sayed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1779039/ebeid-soliman-el-sayed):

Ensure the following services are disabled as they conflict with port 80:

- IIS / SQL Server Reporting Services (ReportServer)
- Web Deployment Agent Service (MsDepSvc)
- BranchCache (PeerDistSvc)
- Sync Share Service (SyncShareSvc)
- World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC)
- Internet Information Server (WAS, IISADMIN)